# Why does scipy.optimize.curve_fit not produce a line of best fit for my points?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a set of data points, (x and y in the code below) and I am trying to create a linear line of best fit through my points. I am using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. My code produces a line, but not a line of best fit. I have tried giving the function model parameters to use for my gradient and for my intercept, but each time it produces the exact same line which does not fit to my data points.

The blue dots are my data points the red line should be fitted to:

[image]

If anyone could point out where I am going wrong I would be extremely grateful:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize as opt

x=[1.0,2.5,3.5,4.0,1.1,1.8,2.2,3.7]
y=[6.008,15.722,27.130,33.772,5.257,9.549,11.098,28.828]
trialX = np.linspace(1.0,4.0,1000)                         #Trial values of x

def f(x,m,c):                                        #Defining the function y(x)=(m*x)+c
    return (x*m)+c

popt,pcov=opt.curve_fit(f,x,y)                       #Returning popt and pcov
ynew=f(trialX,*popt)                                                  

mpl.plot(x,y,'bo')
mpl.plot(trialX,ynew,'r-')
mpl.show()
```

Comment: I managed to figure out the problem by myself. x was defined as a list, not as an array. I fixed it simply by putting np.array at the front of the x and y arrays defined.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion Lizi, I should have seen this comment first! Next time that happens, feel free to post it as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: Note that this has been patched: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3037

Answer (score 6):

You could alternatively use numpy.polyfit to get the line of best fit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

x=[1.0,2.5,3.5,4.0,1.1,1.8,2.2,3.7]
y=[6.008,15.722,27.130,33.772,5.257,9.549,11.098,28.828]
trialX = np.linspace(1.0,4.0,1000)                         #Trial values of x

#get the first order coefficients 
fit = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

#apply 
ynew = trialX * fit[0] + fit[1]                                              

mpl.plot(x,y,'bo')
mpl.plot(trialX,ynew,'r-')
mpl.show()
```

Here is the output:[image]

Comment: You can scale this answer by changing the fit lines to something like: `fit_poly = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))` and `ynew = fit_poly(trialX)`. This makes it easier to change to a quadratic if you want later.

Comment: I've given you another upvote, this should be enough to add pictures to your subsequent posts (and edit this one). Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to add things like "hope this helps", if it does, you'll get votes, if not you'll get downvotes or comments requesting clarification. We try to keep the answers clean here!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This behavior has now been patched in the current version of scipy to make `.curve_fit` a bit more foolproof:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3037

---

For some reason, `.curve_fit` really wants the input to be a numpy array and will give you erroneous results if you pass it a regular list (IMHO this is unexpected behavior and may be a bug). Change the definition of `x` to:

```
x=np.array([1.0,2.5,3.5,4.0,1.1,1.8,2.2,3.7])
```

And you get:

[image]

I'm guessing that the happens since `m*x` where m an integer and x is a list will produce m copies of that list, clearly *not* the result you were looking for!

Comment: this sounds like a bug in curve_fit to me: would you file an issue at  https://github.com/scipy/scipy ?

Comment: @Zhenya I've been thinking about it, it's not quite a bug, but it _is_ unexpected for new users. As such, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3037

Comment: Note: f is **your** function, and curve_fit is just passing **your** x to it. So, you should check that your function has the right behavior for your data. :)