# scipy.optimize.curve_fit failing to estimate the covariance

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I want to fit data to a Logistic (Sigmoid) function and am getting infinite covariance. I have 2 parameters and suppose I have 5 data points. My data are in the variables `xdata` and `ydata`. Here is a code example which generates the exact same warning:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
     y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
     return y

xdata = np.array([  5.,  75.,  88.,  95.,  96.])
ydata = np.array([ 0.04761905, 0.02380952, 0, 0.04761905, 0])


popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
```

which gives `pcov` to be

```
array([[ inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf]])
```

and the following warning:

> OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
>     category=OptimizeWarning)

I saw a related question that led to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725377/why-isnt-curve-fit-able-to-estimate-the-covariance-of-the-parameter-if-the-pa), but there the problem was that the number of data points and parameters was the same, which is not true in my case.

**EDIT**: Notice that above I have mentioned I have data points, but this is just for the example. In reality there are 60. Here is a plot of the raw data, to see that indeed a sigmoid function seems suitable:[image]

Comment: Is the data that you're trying to use different than a set of points of a straight line? can you provide a sample of the real data? Or are you really trying to fit a sigmoid into a linear dataset?

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVergaraKausel. I just added sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the data you provided, I'd say that the warning you get with the resulting covariance matrix is an indication that the sigmoid function is very bad at doing the job of fitting such data.

Moreover, with 5 points is hard to make trends... particularly if you have the first point at 5 and then a jump all the way up to 75. In my opinion, that data looks just like noise. Particularly because you have to points with a y value of 0.

For example, if you try to fit a line

```
def line(x,m,n):
  return x*m+n
```

you'll get two points that seem plausible (first and second) and a well-defined covariance matrix (no warnings).

**Update**

You can also plot the resulting sigmoid function on top of your data to see if the resulting fit is a good one. I suspect that it won't be and thus you get such an ill-defined covariance matrix.

One possible situation is that the fitting cannot find the proper parameters, thus getting lost. I would recommend you to give the fitting procedure some starting values for the parameters that nudge it towards the correct solution. Perhaps `x_0=800` and `k=1`.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edit. My data is moer than 5 points and it does look like a sigmoid, I added the plot.

Comment: The update solved it: indeed the initial guess was too far off

Answer (score 2):

Another problem to watch out for with scipy.optimize.curve_fit(): it is (silently) very particular about the dtype of the x and y data.

In particular, there's no good reason for curve_fit to fail on float32 but succeed on float64 data.  It should even work on int data.  But if it's behaving mysteriously for you, try coercing your data to float64.

see
[Why does scipy.optimize.curve_fit not produce a line of best fit for my points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713689/why-does-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-not-produce-a-line-of-best-fit-for-my-points)

Comment: I would not have guessed it but I just happened to encouter just that problem. x data was of dtype int32 and curve_fit just failed to produce a fit. Coercing to float64 helped that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Common cases:

- [Not enforcing float64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57562555/7441757)
- [Too few data points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632721/7441757)
- [Wrong initial conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632721/7441757)
- Accidentally including wrong input data (e.g. an ID column)